# How to operate on Asymptotic Notation Function Sets ie. Big-O + Big-Omega?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm trying to determine if the following statement is true or false.

**If f(n) ∈ O(n) and g(n) ∈ Ω(n), then f(n) + g(n) ∈ Θ(n).**

I think I understand adding the same asymptotic big-O.  O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
However, I am unsure about adding or operating on the others combined.

For example: 
If f(n) ∈ Θ(n log n), then f(n) * n  = ?

Could this answer be both O(n^2*logn) and Θ(n^2*logn)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the definition of these symbols and try to find a proof or a contradiction example for them.

If `f(n) = O(n)` and `g(n) = Omega(n)`, the `f(n) + g(n)` is not in `Theta(n)` necessarily! As a contradiction, if `f(n) = n` and `g(n) = n^2`, then `f(n) + g(n) = Theta(n^2)`. On the other hand, if `f(n) = n` and `g(n) = n`, then `f(n) + g(n) = Theta(n)`. Hence, you can just say `f(n) + g(n) = Omega(n)` and nothing more.